# How to make multi-line mode line in Emacs 23?

Tags: emacs, modeline

I am using Emacs 23. This comes with OS and I can not change it for some reasons.
Few files I open have long pathnames which are eating all the space and I can not see enabled modes or current line/column. Is there any way to make the mode line multi-line OR some other solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps [SmartModeLine](https://github.com/Bruce-Connor/smart-mode-line/)  would help:

> - Fixed width (if you want): Lets you set a maxium width for the path
>     name and mode names, and truncates them intelligently

Answer (score 2):

Here is a less complex solution, which may be a little easier for you to modify to suit your own -- it uses a simple function called `shorten-directory`:

http://amitp.blogspot.com/2011/08/emacs-custom-mode-line.html